# A strange way to use the adjective "enlightened"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am practicing a listening section of the test TOEFL, and the material gave me a strange sentence. The lecture was about a crop farming in middle ages in Europe.

> The truth was that the Lord of Manor had many rights over the villagers, rights granted by the king. The villagers had to work a set number of days on the lord's land -- typically three days a week -- and they only got to work on their own land once they had finished working on the lord's. It gets worse. The villagers were not allowed to leave the village to work elsewhere, or even marry, without the lord's permission. These were pretty sever obligations. You could call it almost ***enlightened*** slavery.

I actually am having a problem how to translate or understand this adjective in this context. What is the feeling or opinion by native speakers?.

Comment: "Enlightened slavery" is a strange term. There's nothing enlightened about slavery in any form. But the idea is that it's a better (less terrible) form of slavery than the worst kind.

Comment: Poor selection of word. There is no enlightenment about slavery. The text maker should've used ( though they are native speakers ) just "weak" or "soft" thing instead.I agree with ralph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enlightened, in this context, means "having or showing a rational, modern, and well-informed outlook". The people employed by the lord of the manor (called 'serfs') were in some ways like slaves (could be bought, sold, or traded, could not leave the manor) but in other ways not like slaves (in return for working for the lord of the manor,  they were entitled to protection, justice, have their own property, and the right to cultivate certain fields within the manor to grow food for themselves). It is in these latter aspects that serfs differed from slaves. Serfdom, while not being very "enlightened" by modern standards, was a bit more so than slavery.

[Enlightened](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/enlightened)

[Serfdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serfdom)

A related idea is "enlightened (or benevolent) dictatorship" where a government has an authoritarian leader exercises absolute political power over the state but is perceived to do so with regard for benefit of the population as a whole.

Comment: I'm afraid to say, this section was an easy one, so that all information you provided was in the section. That being said, I am sorry to say again like this, I am a bit confused why the adjective leads to mean "having or showing a rational, modern, and well-informed outlook". Especially about a word "outlook". Because the preceding text in the original text says, "These were pretty sever obligations.". But thank you for your answer. Let me kindly add one.

Comment: What are you confused about? Serfdom can be more enlightened than slavery, but still not fully enlightened, like e.g. a democratic society.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand, So the serfdom has much ( or a bit ) more freedom, or more benign, or as you say lords being more "benevolent", thus the word "enlightened" is used. This is a poor selection of word. The lecturer should have used "weakened" or "soft" instead. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @KentaroTomono .. The term "enlightened" here is a historical term of art, referring to the 18th century intellectual movement called the ***Enlightenment***. A number of 18th century monarchs (e.g., Frederick the Great of Prussia and Joseph II of Austria) sought to unite Enlightenment ideals with traditional theories of absolute monarchy in what eventually became known as ***enlightened despotism***. The author of your passage alludes (rather clumsily, in my opinion) to this notion to imply that it was in some sense operative in the feudal age as well.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "the Enlightenment". Absolutely nothing whatsoever. I agree that the piece is written in a clumsy fashion. All it is trying to say is that serfdom was (in a loose way), _" You could call it almost"_ (note!) "enlightened" (not quite as bad as) slavery.